# Preventing unauthed ajax requests from redux actions

Tags: authentication, reactjs, redux, dry, react-redux

I have a component defined like this. `fetchBrands` is a redux action.

```
class Brands extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchBrands();
  }

  render() {
    return (
        // jsx omitted for brevity
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { brands: state.brands.brands }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchBrands: fetchBrands })(Brands);
```

This component is wrapped in a Higher Order Component that looks like this:

```
export default function(ComposedComponent) {
  class Authentication extends Component {

    // kind if like dependency injection
    static contextTypes = {
      router: React.PropTypes.object
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.props.authenticated) {
        this.context.router.push('/');
      }
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
      if (!nextProps.authenticated) {
        this.context.router.push('/');
      }
    }

    render() {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { authenticated: state.auth.authenticated };
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authentication);
}
```

Then, in my router config, I am doing the following:

`<Route path="brands" component={requireAuth(Brands)} />`

If the auth token doesn't exist in local storage, I redirect to a public page. However, the `fetchBrands` action is still being called which is firing off an ajax request. The server is rejecting it because of the lack of an auth token, but I don't want the call to even be made.

```
export function fetchBrands() {
  return function(dispatch) {
     // ajax request here
  }
}
```

I could wrap the ajax request with an `if/else` check, but that isn't very DRY considering all the action functions I'd need to do this in. How can I implement something DRY to prevent the calls if auth fails at the browser level?

Answer (score 0):

You should write a middleware for that. http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html

Since you are using axios I would really recommend using something like https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware

Then you can use a middleware like

```
const tokenMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if (action.payload && action.payload.request && action.payload.request.secure) {
    const { auth: { isAuthenticated } } = store.getState()
    const secure = action.payload.request.secure

    if (!isAuthenticated && secure) {
      history.push({ pathname: 'login', query: { next: history.getCurrentLocation().pathname } })
      return Promise.reject(next({ type: 'LOGIN_ERROR', ...omit(action, 'payload') }))
    }
  }

  return next(action)
}
```

action.payload.request.secure is a custom prop I use to indicate the request needs authentication.

I this case I also redirect using history from react-router but you can handle this to dispatch another action (store.dispatch({ whatever })) and react as you need

Comment: With axios and using promise middleware.